# SDL2 + Opengl Black Window on Mac

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

i am trying to use SDL2 and OpenGL on mac osx yosemite, i have followed the example on SDL page and also the example from Lazy Foo's Page http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/50_SDL_and_opengl_2/index.php but everytime i run the code, i get the same result, a blank window with black background, i have searched on google for a while now, but ive still not gotten any solution, i'd appreciate any help

Below is my code

```
/*
 * Main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 15, 2015
 *      Author: Damian-Machine
 */
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include<SDL.h>
#include<SDL_opengl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

bool init();

bool initGL();

void handleKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

void update();

void render();

void close();

SDL_Window *gWindow = NULL;

SDL_GLContext gContext;

bool gRenderQuad = true;

int main(){
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit = false;
    if(!init()){
        printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    SDL_StartTextInput();


    while(!quit){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) !=0){
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                quit = true;
            }else if (e.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT){
                int x = 0, y = 0;
                SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                handleKeys(e.text.text[0], x, y);
            }

        }

        render();
    }

    SDL_StopTextInput();

    close();
}

bool init(){
    bool success = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }else{
        printf("SDL Opengl context created successfully\n");
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);


        printf("Checking failed status: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

        //std::cout << "OpenGL version " << glGetString​(GL_VERSION​) << std::endl;
      //std::cout << "GLSL version " << glGetString​(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION​​) << std::endendl;
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }else { //Create context
            gContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( gWindow );
            if( gContext == NULL ) {
                printf( "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = false;
            } else { //Use Vsync
                if( SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval( 1 ) < 0 ) {
                    printf( "Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                } //Initialize OpenGL
                if( !initGL() ) {
                    printf( "Unable to initialize OpenGL!\n" ); success = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return success;
}

bool initGL(){
    bool success = true;

    GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR){
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL! %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR){
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }

    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

    error = glGetError();
    if(error != GL_NO_ERROR){
        printf("Error initializing OpenGL %s\n", gluErrorString(error));
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void handleKeys( unsigned char key, int x, int y ) {
    //Toggle quad
    if( key == 'q' )
    {
        gRenderQuad = !gRenderQuad;
    }
}

void update(){

}

void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(gRenderQuad){
        glRotatef(0.4f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);    // Rotate The cube around the Y axis
        glRotatef(0.2f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f( -0.5f, -0.5f );
            glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f );
            glVertex2f( 0.5f, 0.5f );
            glVertex2f( -0.5f, 0.5f );
        glEnd();
    }
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gWindow);
}

void close(){
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: You're creating a core profile context (`SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE`), More than half of the OpenGL calls you use are deprecated, and not supported in the core profile. All the matrix stack functionality, immediate mode drawing, etc., is unavailable in the core profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Reto Koradi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3530129/reto-koradi) said, it's a version mismatch. OpenGL has gone through lots of changes over the decades, and the “core” profile disables older features that you and LazyFoo are using.

LazyFoo page 50 uses OpenGL 2.1 features, but your code is specifying that you'll only use core 4.1 features. Remove these lines:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
```

to make your code run. However it will only produce a blank red screen. Remove this line:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

to get the green quad to show up on the screen:

[image: SDL Tutorial]

Alternatively, if you want to use the depth buffer, leave that `glEnable` line in, and change your `glClear` to:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Check out [LazyFoo page 51](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/) to see how things are written in a more modern  OpenGL. It's completely different! You have to write shaders, implement rotation yourself, put all the vertices into buffers. I learned OpenGL back with the old features and am now having to re-learn everything…

Comment: Hi @amitp Thanks for the help, i've made the changes you suggested but i still get a blank black screen, i still can't figure out what ive done wrong

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to mention that i was using eclipse, i tried the exact same code on eclipse and it works beautifully well, but im still concerned, why it works on xcode but not on eclipse, thanks anyways